# Angular google maps in modal ng-if not render map correctly

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, modal-dialog

Hi I read many issues how to put google map into modal.
I found good solution with ng-if but my map doesn't render correctly... I tried also refresh but didn't help. Any idea why?

[image]

```
<div class="popup" ng-show="showMap = true">
    <ui-gmap-google-map ng-if="showMap" class="map" center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' options="map.options"></ui-gmap-google-map>
    <div class="location">
        <div class="address">Columbus, Ohio, Street 21</div>
        <span class="circle">
            <i class="material-icons">place</i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.map = {
    center: {
        latitude: 45,
        longitude: -73
    },
    zoom: 8
};
```